# How to compile OpenCV in HEVC with Cmake?

Tags: opencv, cmake, hevc, libx265

I am modifying HEVC opensource project downloaded from bitbucket.
I have added OpenCV libraries now for some frame processing.
Code works fine with visual studio.
Problem is when I try to make it with cmake following error is producing:

```
libx265.so.102: undefined reference to `cv::dilate(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
```

Comment: Without knowing **what exact lines** you have modified it is difficult to say anything.

Comment: i have compiled it with cmake by adding opencv lib in CMakeLists.txt and it compiled without any error.                                                                                                but when i compiled the libraries of x265 it to add in ffmpeg as an exernal library it give me the same error that occurs before when CMakeLists.txt had not entry of opencv.